# React Authentication By Example tutorial with Auth0 stuck

Tags: reactjs, react-router, auth0

I am just starting out with React and Authentication. I have to use Auth0 for my course but they don't give us any support on how to use it. I've tried following the tutorial on https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/react/basic-authentication but the starter application just comes up with a blank screen. It requires React Router 5, and I was wondering if that was the problem but package.json seems to install that version, so it doesn't seem to be that.

Do I continue with the tutorial and will it work once I've gone through all the authorisation work? Or is something fundamentally wrong now? If anyone has done this and knows the answer, I would be most obliged to know. Failing that, I'll update this if I get any farther.

I installed the spa demo app and expected to see a dummy app but all I get is a black screen. The tutorial is for installing Auth0 so I don't know if I need to do that first before anything appears, but that seems odd.

Comment: It's not clear to me what specific reproducible coding issue you are asking for help with. Can you edit your post to include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using? If there are errors, please also share them and any accompanying code stacktraces. Try to include any debugging steps you've already taken.

Comment: That said, `react-router` had a big version change this past year, which broke and continues to break just about every tutorial out there that for reasons unknown just haven't updated their curriculum and fail to warn students/readers about it. Check what version you've *actually* installed by running `npm list react-router` in the terminal in the project directory. Make sure you didn't accidentally install v6 by mistake. Or if you want to stick to v6, read through the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) for all the breaking changes.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese. Thanks so much for your replies. Basically, I installed the starter repo that is linked to in that article git clone -b starter git@github.com:auth0-developer-hub/spa_react_javascript_hello-world.git. But after doing npm i, creating an .env file for the react app and starting the local database, everything comes up as a blank screen. I am not sure if that is what is supposed to happen - I was hoping anyone who had followed the tutorial could shed some light. I did an npm install and it did install version 5

Comment: Well, without seeing what code you are using it's pretty much impossible to say why it is or isn't working for any reason. You are working with this [repo](https://github.com/auth0-developer-hub/spa_react_javascript_hello-world) yes? From what I can tell you should be able to clone the repo and run `npm i` to install dependencies and then `npm start` to start the app. Try simplifying what the app is rendering, and incrementally add UI back 1 component at-a-time until it breaks, and repeat the process on that component until you find where it's breaking.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.